# Buildozer and Py4a cannot build pysendfile using kivy

Tags: python, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to use pysendfile module for my code which works fine on laptop. But when i try to build the same for android using `buildozer android debug` , it throws following error. I have included `requirements=pysendfile` in my `buildozer.spec` file.

```
Failed building wheel for pysendfile
Running setup.py clean for pysendfile
Failed to build pysendfile
Installing collected packages: pysendfile
Running setup.py install for pysendfile: started
Running setup.py install for pysendfile: finished with status 'error'
Complete output from command /home/heman/kivy/mobile/.buildozer/venv/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-EFXqLT/pysendfile/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-GvNKlz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/heman/kivy/mobile/.buildozer/venv/include/site/python2.7/pysendfile --home=/tmp/tmputyngD:
running install
running build
running build_ext
building 'sendfile' extension
creating build
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
/bin/false -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c sendfilemodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/sendfilemodule.o
error: command '/bin/false' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/home/heman/kivy/mobile/.buildozer/venv/bin/python2.7 -u -c"
import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build EFXqLT/pysendfile/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-GvNKlz-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/heman/kivy/mobile/.buildozer/venv/include/site/python2.7/pysendfile --home=/tmp/tmputyngD" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-EFXqLT/pysendfile/
Command failed: pip install --target=/home/heman/kivy/mobile/.buildozer/applibs pysendfile

Buildozer failed to execute the last command
The error might be hidden in the log above this error
Please read the full log, and search for it before
raising an issue with buildozer itself.
In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

EDIT: this is my recipe

```
from pythonforandroid.toolchain import PythonRecipe


class PysendfileRecipe(PythonRecipe):
    name='pysendfile'
    version = '2.0.1'

    url = 'https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pysendfile/pysendfile-{version}.tar.gz'
    depends = ['python2']
    site_packages_name = 'sendfile'

recipe = PysendfileRecipe()
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens because pysendfile's build process apparently involves some compilation but it has no compilation recipe in python-for-android. Right now python-for-android tries to install it with pip but that fails because the environment isn't set up to target android (instead it's set up to fail so as to catch the problem).

The solution is to add a recipe to python-for-android to do the compilation. There's some information about this [here](http://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/).

Comment: I created a recipe for pysendfile and saved it at /python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/pysendfile. The terminal still says pysendfile don't have recipes. Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: You placed it in the python-for-android folder that buildozer is using?

Comment: i placed it here :  /home/heman/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/pysendfile .Which folder are you talking about?

Comment: python-for-android is a python program. Do you ahve that installed in /home/heman/python-for-android? If not, that's just a meaningless folder.

Comment: And did you tell buildozer to use this python-for-android installation?

Comment: Yes, But it still gives me the same error. Check my recipe file above if there is any mistake?

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't using your recipe, but it wouldn't work in any case because a PythonRecipe won't do the compilation it needs. You can use a CythonRecipe if it's cython, or possibly a CompiledComponentsPythonRecipe.

Comment: i cloned the py4a git repo at /home/heman/python-for-android/ but the recipes folder is present in /home/heman/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes. I placed my recipe here which is not recognized. I have also given the path as /home/heman/python-for-android/ in buildozer . If there is any path problem, what is it? 
another error can be in my recipe file. I have not created recipe.sh file but a __init__.py file only. is that okay? help me out @inclement

Comment: Could you try deleting the .buildozer folder in your build directory then running buildozer again?

Comment: I did it but there is a problem in python for android. Buildozer now says you are using old toolchain for py4a though I cloned it from github